# Is there way to stream CSV object from S3 bucket to AWS lambda using boto3?

Tags: json, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

Is there a way to stream data back and forth to AWS lambda using Boto3?
I have a working code but that loads CSV data into memory process it and put it in s3 Object. I am rather looking for a way to stream object from S3 using Boto3 and streaming it back to S3.

```py
import csv
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    targetbucket = 'AWS_BUCKET_NAME'
    csvkey = 'CSV_FILENAME.csv'
    jsonkey = 'JSON_FILENAME.json'

    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    csv_object = s3.Object(targetbucket, csvkey)
    csv_content = csv_object.get()['Body'].read().splitlines()
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    result = []

    for line in csv_content:
        x = json.dumps(line.decode('utf-8')).split(',')
        Name = str(x[0])
        Title = str(x[1])
        Age = str(x[2])
        jsonData = '{ "Name": ' + Name + '"' + ','  \
            + ' "Title": ' + '"' + Title + '"' + ',' \
            + ' "Age": ' + '"' +  Age + '"' + '}'
        result.append(jsonData)

    s3_client.put_object(
        Bucket=targetbucket,
        Body= str(result).replace("'",""),
        Key=jsonkey
    )
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about your actual use-case? For example, what triggers the conversion job? Do you want it to be done whenever a new object is placed in S3? Do you want to convert the contents of the file and store it back in the same name, or put it somewhere different? (Wouldn't that overwrite existing output files?) It appears that you wish to convert from CSV to JSON, is that correct? (By the way, your code is referring to `Name` and `Age` before they are defined.) If you can edit your question to tell us your actual goal, we are more likely to be able to provide good suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried using the streams API?

Comment: I end up using smart_open. Here is the link of smart_open: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open

Answer (score 1):

For streaming data from a CSV/JSON file in S3, you can possibly use '[S3 Select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html)'. Using this, you stream the data directly to your code and use it instead of downloading the file in your memory and processing it.

Apart from that, you can also perform basic SQL statements on the code.

You can also refer to this code for references: https://gist.github.com/SrushithR/1dbb6d3521383c259b47756506cf5955

Answer (score 1):

I end up using smart_open: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open Here is an example from its README.

```
>>> # can use context managers too:
>>> with open('smart_open/tests/test_data/1984.txt.gz') as fin:
...    with open('smart_open/tests/test_data/1984.txt.bz2', 'w') as fout:
...        for line in fin:
...           fout.write(line)
```

You can open a file in the s3 bucket with a URL that looks like this: s3://my_bucket/my_key